# Minecraft FPS stuck at 60 fps

Tags: graphics, minecraft, framerate

My Minecraft is stuck at 60 fps.
I tried using Lunar Client to see if it was a problem installing, and it wasn't.

I tried disabling VSync on Minecraft & it didn't worked.
But when I press F3 to see how many fps I have, it shows more than 144 (~500)
I tried using full screen mode, using 1920x1080, nothing worked ...

But i'm sure i'm not getting 144 FPS on my screen

I know I can get more than 60 fps because when I was on Windows, I was able to get like 1 000 fps. I don't have any others things in my background. But the weirdest thing is like it's showing me that I have more than 60 fps but I dont' get it

Is there any reason why it can't show me 144 Fps?

Using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Hi and welcome. What does FPS have to do with hz?

Comment: Thanks, I don't really know, maybe it could help people to understand my problem

Comment: No it cant you are telling me about apples and asking a question about pears.

Comment: Oh okay sorry

Comment: No need to be sorry I would suggest to you to read up on what the 2 terms mean.

Answer (score 0):

In minecraft, there is a slider with the max fps. If you slide that to max (or min, i forgot), you get unlimited fps. I think it is at the minecraft video settings.

If that doesn't work, maybe you can tweak in the Ubuntu display settings to bump up the refresh rate. I don't have any experience with this, because my ubuntu always defaults to my native resolution and refresh rate (full hd and 60hz if you want to know).

Comment: I tried using the bar to switch FPS but it didn't worked, and how can I use "twear" to change this? Because i've already changed the refresh rate to 144 in my normal settings

Comment: what do you mean with twear? can't you just slide the bar?

Comment: I did it, I made it to max, i go back and I don't get 144 fps

Comment: Then you should just maybe be happy with something that looks like 60 fps. Can you really see the difference? (i play competative on 60hz)